# Android start drag from touched position

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, touch, move

I want to move a textview with drag and drop. and give it a new position.

I use following code:

```
ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");

                        double rotationRad = Math.toRadians(view.getRotation());
                        final int w = (int) (view.getWidth() * view.getScaleX());
                        final int h = (int) (view.getHeight() * view.getScaleY());
                        double s = Math.abs(Math.sin(rotationRad));
                        double c = Math.abs(Math.cos(rotationRad));
                        final int width = (int) (w * c + h * s);
                        final int height = (int) (w * s + h * c);
                        final View v = view;

                        View.DragShadowBuilder shadow = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view) {
                            @Override
                            public void onDrawShadow(Canvas canvas) {
                                canvas.scale(v.getScaleX(), v.getScaleY(), width / 2, height / 2);
                                canvas.rotate(v.getRotation(), width / 2, height / 2);
                                canvas.translate((width - v.getWidth()) / 2, (height - v.getHeight()) / 2);
                                super.onDrawShadow(canvas);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onProvideShadowMetrics(Point shadowSize, Point shadowTouchPoint) {
                                shadowSize.set(width, height);
                                shadowTouchPoint.set(shadowSize.x / 2, shadowSize.y / 2);
                            }
                        };
                        view.startDrag(data, shadow, view, 0);
```

Right now the drag shadow is always build from the center of the touched image view.

How do i build the drag shadow exactly from the point where i touch the view?

Comment: how about capturing the point where the view has been touched and make it the center for you translation? override the onTouch(MotionEvent e) method and get the touch positions

Answer (score 2):

`shadowTouchPoint.set()` function is where you tell `startDrag()` function to start the drag from.
So in your code,
change `shadowTouchPoint.set(shadowSize.x / 2, shadowSize.y / 2)`
to `shadowTouchPoint.set(desiredX, desiredY)`

So in your requirement, those will be nothing but `motionEvent.getX()` and `motionEvent.getY()` from your `onTouch()` of your view.

Here is how it would look like,

```
public class TouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(final View view, final MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
                View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);
                view.startDrag(data, new View.DragShadowBuilder(view) {
                    @Override
                    public void onProvideShadowMetrics(Point shadowSize, Point shadowTouchPoint) {
                        shadowSize.set(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight());
                        shadowTouchPoint.set((int) motionEvent.getX(), (int) motionEvent.getY());
                    }
                }, view, 0);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

and TouchListener for view would be

```
view.setOnTouchListener(new TouchListener());
```